# 01/01/1753 date is corrupt in Excel after export from SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2012, excel, ssrs-2008-r2

The date `01/01/1753` appears fine in the SSRS 208R2 report preview, but when the report is exported to Excel 2010, it appears as `###########` and the value in the cell is `-53689`. All other dates come across just fine.

Apparently Excel accepts `01/01/1753` input and displays the dates correctly when manually entered.

Is there any method to display the SSRS reports containing the `01/01/1753` dates in Excel correctly as well?

PS: I was not able to find any relevant information on this using google. It seems to ignore the numbers and return mostly the articles on how to sort the worksheets by date.

Comment: Do you have a legitimate reason for using that date anyway? Or is it some sort of sentinel value that should be `NULL`?

Comment: The earliest date supported by SQL Server DATETIME is 1753/01/01.  But Excel's earliest date is apparently 1900/01/01.  (If you have a 0 in the Excel column you get the non-date of 1/0/1900.)

Answer (score 3):

Excel specifically provides a message: Dates and times that are negative or too large are displayed as ######.

So, that is a Excel limit.  Further, you can type in strings that look like dates, but Excel may not think of them as dates. For example, if I make a column of date type and enter into the columns -53689, 01/01/1753, and 01/01/1900 (using my settings) I get this:

```
####################
01/01/1753
            1/1/1900
```

So, it is easy to see that these are not all being interpreted the same by Excel.

Comment: Not sure how that helps :(

Comment: It does not help you get what you were hoping for directly, but it does help you know what is stopping you.  **Suggestion:** See if you can configure the Excel column as TEXT and *actually convert* the SQL Server `Date` value into a character string before running the report into Excel.

Comment: That won't work, as a new workbook is created every time. My only option so it seems is to convert the column to varchar before outputting to the report. This is how I am going to proceed.

Comment: In Excel a ' in front of a number string will prevent it from converting, but the ' will be there physically. E.g. '01/01/1753  (In case the text string does not get handled as expected.)

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of date column in design part on the SSRS.
This is the compress problem on excel sheet.
so give the full space for date and time which will appear on full length.